# Removing list of itens from concurrent_unordered_map

Tags: c++, concurrency

I need to remove all items from my concurrent_unordered_map where the value is true

```
auto dataMap = new concurrency::concurrent_unordered_map<std::string, bool>();
(*dataMap)["1"] = false;
(*dataMap)["2"] = true;
(*dataMap)["3"] = false;
(*dataMap)["4"] = true;
(*dataMap)["5"] = false;
(*dataMap)["6"] = true;
```

I did a long search to see how to do this correctly but, I don't find some solution... my last try:

```
auto itr = dataMap->begin();
while (itr != dataMap->end())
{
    auto data = (*itr);
    if (data.second == true)
    {
        dataMap->unsafe_erase(data.first);
    }

    ++itr;
}
```

So, how to remove the items, correctly ?

Edit:

I'm using VC++ 2019

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot use `++` on iterator to erased element. Accessing object which was deleted leads to undefined behaviour.

`unsafe_erase` returns the iterator to the first item past erased one (or `end` if erased was the last one).

So you can write:

```
while (itr != dataMap->end())
{
    auto data = (*itr);
    if (data.second == true)
        itr = dataMap->unsafe_erase(data.first);
    else
        ++itr;
}
```